# inserting filesize column in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I'm trying to add a file size column into my mysqli query but I'm not sure the proper way do do this inside this loop. I tried just`$_FILES[file][size]`. but I wasn't hopeful this would work. Can anyone enlighten me as to the correct way to achieve this. Thanks

```
 foreach  ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name) {

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key],"test/$name"))
 {
  mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO files VALUES('$_GET[draft]','$name','$_FILES[file][size]')");
 }
}
```

Comment: what is the name of your input of type file ?

Comment: the file input name is 'file'

Answer (score 1):

Assumig you have in your HTML code

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myFile1" />
    <input type="file" name="myFile2" />
    ....
    ...// other input and your submit input
</form>
```

The structure of your `$_FILES` will be

```
Array
(
    [myFile1] => Array
        (
            [name] => XXX
            [type] => XXX
            [tmp_name] => XXX
            [error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK  (= 0)
            [size] => XXXX
        )

    [myFile2] => Array
        (
            [name] => XXXX
            [type] => XXXX
            [tmp_name] => XXXX
            [error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
            [size] => XXXX
        )
    etc..
)
```

Then you can do

```
// Loop on each entry of $_FILES
foreach($_FILES as $nameOfInputFile => $fileStructure) {

    // Check the error status first, skip the file if an error occured
    if ($fileStructure['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
        continue;

    // $fileStructure contain the current file data
    if(move_uploaded_file($fileStructure['tmp_name'],"test/" . $fileStructure['name']))
    {
        mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO files VALUES('" . $_POST['draft'] . "','$name','" . $fileStructure['size'] . "')");
    }

}
```

Note: As you are posting file, your draft value should retrieve with `$_POST`